# Getting not NULL values from three columns in one column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, null

As you can see, I have three columns with the important features for me (a, b, c, d, e, f) - no matter of size. I want to copy them into new column `"name"`. The problem is when I try to copy with `case`, or `if`, or anything else it doesn't work. For example:

[image]

If I want to copy `"name1"` to `"name"`, I will get 'a', 'b' and `NULL`, then after that I try to copy `"name 2"` I get 'c' and 'd', but also `NULL` at the place where it should be 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: You should research the `COALESCE` SQL function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression that utilizes the [`concat()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#concat) function:

```
concat("name1", "name2", "name3")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (as was mentioned by @Vince) is to use the [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#coalesce) function, like:

```
coalesce("test1", "test2")
```

[image: example]